# How to split a string by continuous same letter in R

Tags: r, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
s <- "aaehhhhhhhaannd"
```

How can I split the string into the following format with R?

```
c("aa", "e", "hhhhhhh", "aa","nn","d")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a base R `strsplit` with a PCRE regex based on [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
s <- "aaehhhhhhhaannd"
strsplit(s, "(?<=(.))(?!\\1)", perl=TRUE)
# [[1]]
# [1] "aa"      "e"       "hhhhhhh" "aa"      "nn"      "d"
```

See the [R demo online](http://ideone.com/S7OHuu) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JNgWp/1).

**Regex details**:

- `(?<=(.))`  - a positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) that "looks" left and *captures* any char into Group 1 with `(.)` [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (this value can be referred to from inside the pattern with the help of a `\1` [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html))
- `(?!\\1)`  - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is the same value as captured into Group 1 immediately to the right of the current location.

Since the lookarounds are not consuming text, the split occurs at the location between different characters.

NOTE: If you want `.` to match a newline, too, add `(?s)` at the start of the pattern (as in PCRE regex, `.` does not match line breaks by default).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str_extract_all`, with regex `(.)\\1*` which uses back reference to match repetitive characters:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("aaehhhhhhhaannd", "(.)\\1*")
#[[1]]
#[1] "aa"      "e"       "hhhhhhh" "aa"      "nn"      "d"
```